# how can i improve the accuracy of pocketsphinx open source speech recognition API for English language?

Tags: api, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

In order to convert speech-to-text I am using cmusphinx opensource API which convert .wav audio format into text and uses the language model for particular input speech-language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pocket Sphinx accuracy is completely based on the model used. In order to achieve better results try to train your acoustic model according to the target user. 
If you don't want to train your own model try changing various parameters of `feat.params` like `-cmninit`.

Moreover, try to set `recognizer.setKeywordThreshold()` to as min as possible, I prefer `recognizer.setKeywordThreshold(1e-40f)`